# Handling async file upload with Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I'm pretty new to React and Redux, and I'm having some trouble coming up with the best way to structure asynchronous file upload.

What I want is

1. The user hits a form's submit button
2. Files are uploaded, and the paths that they're uploaded at are returned from the server
3. The state gets updated with those paths before a final POST request gets sent

What I'm thinking of doing now is passing the form or some higher up component into an action handler, like so

```
// actions.js
// using redux-thunk middleware, so this action creator
// dispatches actions on success and error events
submitForm({ formElement }) {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    // ... do some stuff

    fetch('/files', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: new FormData(formElement)
    })
    .then(() => dispatch(uploadSuccess()));
  }
}
```

Is this a bad idea? Is there a better way to get `FormData` than passing the form element to the action creator?

Comment: I think you've got the right idea using redux-thunk, check here for a full async example: http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html#-actions-js

Comment: Is your new FormData(formElement) a serialized data of your form, if yes, you would give this data instead of formElement?

Comment: If you add an `onChange` listener to your input, the event that's passed will have a `files` property that represents a [FileList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList). Track this in your component and pass it on submit. Then in your action creator you can iterate over the file list and add each file to the FormData using append.

Comment: @MichaelRasoahaingo The form data would include files, which isn't serializable. I want to upload the files before finally submitting the form.

Comment: @Jazy48 Oh, that means you need to make two requests; one to upload the files, one to submit the rest of the form. Can't really be done in the same request.

Comment: Right @AlexGuerra. Also, with a slight modification your answer works perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [Alex Guerra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37602195/handling-async-file-upload-with-redux?noredirect=1#comment62689649_37602195)~

Didn't realize I could simply bind an event to the file input's `onChange`. What I'm doing now is

```
render() {
  const { onChangeFiles, index } = this.props;
  return (
    // ... some other stuff, then
    <input type="file" onChange={
      (e) => {
        onChangeFiles({ files: e.target.files, index });
      }
    } />
  )
}
```

Then adding those files to the component's state. Then, in the final submit handler I'll `POST` the files in the state object before making a final post request after the upload finishes.